# How to execute code after multi level subscribe in angular

Tags: angular

I need to be able to execute a call back after Observable subcribe has been processed.

I have a component "A" that has function to call firebase data with mutli level subscription and i need to executed other processed after all subscription has been processed.

i had to try the solution follow the tutorial from this https://angular.io/guide/comparing-observables and other solution i had found about this, but not working.

here is my function to call subscription  :

```
    alldata:any[] = []
  getAllFirebaseData(){
    
    let listFilter:any[] = [
      {field:"entry_date", operator:">=", value:new Date("2020-10-01 00:00:00")},
      {field:"entry_date", operator:"<=", value:new Date("2020-10-05 00:00:00")},
    ]
    //first subcription
    this.getFirebaseData("collection1"
    ,''
    , false
    , listFilter
    , 30
    ).subscribe(res=>{
      if(res instanceof Array){
        console.log("run 1")
        res.map(pl=>{
          var path = pl.payload.doc.ref.path.split("/")
          var data = pl.payload.doc.data() 
          this.alldata.push(data)

          //second subcription
          if(data.field1 == "value"){
            this.getFirebaseData("collection2"
            ,''
            , false
            , [{field:"field1", operator:"==", value:data.field1}]
            , 30
            ).subscribe(res2=>{
              if(res2 instanceof Array){
                console.log("run 2")
                res2.map(pl2=>{
                  var path = pl2.payload.doc.ref.path.split("/")
                  var data2 = pl2.payload.doc.data() 
                  this.alldata.push(data2)

                  //for some condition, sometime here still need more subcription
                })
              }
            })

          }

        })
      }
    })
    //other process after all alldata is already pushed to this.alldata
  }
```

i try to call the method by this

```
let promise = new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.getAllFirebaseData()

});
promise.then(value => {
  console.log("run other process")
});
```

and this

```
const observable = new Observable<number>(observer => {
  this.getAllFirebaseData()
});

// initiate execution
observable.subscribe(value => {
  console.log("run other process")
    
});
```

but both are not working, am i missing something??

I would be glad for any help.

Comment: There are multiple issues here. You need to replace nested subscriptions with an higher order mapping operator like `switchMap`. And replace parallel subscriptions with functions like `forkJoin`.

Comment: You're probably looking for a `forkJoin`

Comment: @MichaelD thanks for answer, forkJoin and switchMap, i will try to search for more information... thanks again

Comment: @AdityaMenon thanks for answer, forkJoin and switchMap, i will try to search for more information... thanks again